# Understanding: different size in YOLO v5 in inference

Tags: python, image, yolo, inference, yolov5

I am using YoloV5 and I found that it works in inference with arbitrary image size and aspect ratio. I have done mostly image classification (EfficientNet, MobileNet, .. ) and so I was wondering how it can perform classification with different input size?

It performs a fixed resize to a common dimension?
It has more classification heads?